# d3.js graphing sub arrays from JSON

Tags: arrays, json, d3.js

So I am attempting to draw a simple line graph. The path to the arrays are fairly long, It seems the forEach function is not looping through the array? Am I missing a function to successfully create d.date which comes out as 'null' and d.air which comes out as 'NaN'?

data[0].STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.date_time, and data[0].STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.air_temp_set_1 are the arrays I want to plot

Here it is on blockbuilder:
http://blockbuilder.org/TMoore24/b9906fd3893034b91f13e0c86acb2f75

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things going on here.

(1):

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = format(data[0].STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.date_time);
    d.air = +data[0].STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.air_temp_set_1;
});
```

These don't work because both `data[0].STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.date_time`, and `data[0].STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.air_temp_set_1` are arrays.

What you probably want is this.

```
var obs = data[0].STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS;
var dates = obs.date_time.map(format);
var air = obs.air_temp_set_1.map(function(d){ return +d; });

data.date = dates;
data.air = air;
```

What this leaves you with is an array of dates and and array of air temps.

*Unfortunately*, this leads to issue #2.

(2)

```
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.air); });
```

This function assumes that each object, `d`, takes the form `{date: SINGLE_DATE_VALUE, air: SINGLE_NUMERIC_VALUE, etc}` but what you actually have is `data = {date:[ARRAY_OF_DATES, air: ARRAY_OF_TEMPERATURES, etc...}`

To use the `line` function above, then you need to create an array of objects of the form `{date: DATE_VALUE, air: AIR_TEMPERATURE_VALUE}`. There are various ways you can do that depending on how you want your final data structured. Here's one way:

```
data.airTempByDate = data.date.map(function(d, i){
    return {
        date: d,
        air: air[i]
    };
});
```

---

Hope this makes sense! [Here's a working block on blockbuilder](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/ce688f8eb7ffa2fdc5f5442743e2f7d0) with the fixes above.

Comment: Got it, so the forEach function loops through each Object which was an array in my case.

Comment: Actually, `forEach` will *only* loop through Arrays. It will throw an error if you try to use it on an Object of the form `{key: value}`. E.g. `obj = {a:1, b:2}; obj.forEach(console.log)` will throw the error: `'obj.forEach' is undefined` since Objects don't have a forEach function.